# Можно ли как то именовать клоужеры?

Tags: ios, swift

Я новичок в свифт и вот сейчас на теме клоужеры возник такой вопрос, я понимаю их преимущество и удобство использования, но вопрос в том, что когда  к примеру нужно написать 3 функции 3 разных клоужера, то понять, что они делают можно только лишь разобравшись в коде...

Ведь мы не даем никакого названия им... Как по мне это очень не удобно, сидеть читать весь клоужер, чтоб понять что он делает.

Можно ли как то его именовать?

Пример

```
func filterArray(array: [Int], f: (Int) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
  var filtered = [Int]()
  for value in array {
    if f (value){
      filtered.append(valeu)
    }
  }
 return filtered
}

filterArray(numbers) {$0 % 2 == 0}
filterArray(numbers) {$0 % 2 == 1}
```

В данном случае я так понял что именно вот эта часть кода называется клоужером `{$0 % 2 == 0}` и она отличается от этой `{$0 % 2 == 1}` , но понять это можно только разобравшись в том, что они делают.

Мне кажется, что все же если вместо кложера определять функции, именовать их и передавать в функцию, то будет понятно что что мы подаем... А так получается что клоужер это как анонимная функция, что делает которая можно понять только прочитав ее.

Comment: можете привести пример?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил

Comment: Кстати, есть довольно часто используемое слово «замыкание».

Comment: @VladD кстати есть очень много часто используемых слов в повседневной речи. Тут все наверное зависит от человека и его сферы деятельности... стеб))

Answer (score 2):

Для того оно и клоужеры, чтобы выполнять несложные или очевидные функции. В ином случае лучше использовать функции со значениями и комментировать участки кода :)

Answer (score 0):

В Swift как функцию так и замыкание можно присвоить переменной.

Вот пример:

```
var closure:(Int)->Bool = { number in
    return number % 2 == 0
}

func isIntegerEven(integer: Int, closure:(Int)->Bool) {
    if closure(integer) {
        print("Число четное")
    } else {
        print("Число не четное")
    }
}

isIntegerEven(integer: 3, closure: closure)
```

Создаем переменную `closure` и устанавливаем ей замыкание как значение. Далее создаем функцию `isIntegerEven`, в которую передаем число и замыкание. В теле функции вызывается замыкание в которое передается число для проверки -  четное или нет. Далее вызывается функция с параметрами.

Таким образом Вы можете именовать замыкания. В Вашем примере:

```
func filterArray(array: [Int], f: (Int) -> Bool) -> [Int]
```

именем замыкания является `f`.